# pull style format from reference table

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I am just starting HTML / CSS and have the following query:

I want to pull the style format (such as bold, italic) from a reference table using free marker script.

I tried applying text-transform property in the HTML and the values as bold, italic in reference table. The below script is not making the text as bold / italic as in reference table:

```
${LISTInternalID.JoinedAttribute.ReferenceTableInternalID.ReferencetableAttribute}
```

Please help.